# cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() missing operator

Tags: c#

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.Text == "Add")
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO LibraryInfo (First_Name,MI,Last_Name,Address,Municipality,Province,textbox7) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}',{5}','{6}')",
            txtFName.Text.Trim(),
            txtMI.Text.Trim(),
            txtLName.Text.Trim(),
            txtAddress.Text.Trim(),
            cboMunicipality.Text.Trim(),
            cboProvince.Text.Trim(),
            textbox.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"UPDATE LibraryInfo SET First_Name='{0}',MI='{1}',Last_Name='{2}',Address='{3}',Municipality='{4}',Province='{5}',textbox7='{6}' WHERE ID={7}",
            txtFName.Text.Trim(),
            txtMI.Text.Trim(),
            txtLName.Text.Trim(),
            txtAddress.Text.Trim(),
            cboMunicipality.Text,
            cboProvince.Text,
            textbox.Text.Trim(),
            txtID.Text);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        this.Dispose();
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

//it says that: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Cavite','Graduate')'.
//Cavite is the Province and Graduate is the textbox7

Comment: Sigh; DO NOT CONCATENATE USER INPUT INTO SQL. Ever.

Answer (score 4):

You SQL statement is missing a quote before `{5}`:

```
"INSERT INTO LibraryInfo (First_Name,MI,Last_Name,Address,Municipality,Province,textbox7) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}')"
```

Most importantly, this is the best way of getting you in trouble. You should use parameters instead of creating the SQL statement yourself.

For each parameter use something similar to this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFName.Text.Trim());
```

Then use `@firstname` in your sql:

```
"INSERT INTO LibraryInfo (First_Name, ...) VALUES(@firstname, ...')"
```

Further reading: the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @tokazaki: Need more help?

Answer (score 4):

Never *ever* (I mean **ever**) use `String.Format` to pass parameters to queries!! Use parameterized queries instead.

In your case that could look like this:

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO LibraryInfo First_Name,MI,Last_Name,Address,Municipality,Province,textbox7) VALUES(@firstName, @middleName @lastName, @address, ...)");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", txtMI.Text.Trim());
...
```

Why?

1. No SQL injections
2. Hassle free type conversion (`DateTime`, `float`, etc.)
3. Look Ma! No missing single quotes!

Answer (score 1):

What you need are: parameters; for example:

```
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE LibraryInfo SET First_Name=@firstName,MI=@mi,Last_Name=@lastName,Address=@address ... WHERE ID=@id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mi", txtMI.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtFName.Text.Trim());
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
```

Note the lack of `'` quotes around the parameters, and the lack of `string.Format`.

What you have now is basically an invite "please come and take all my data then destroy my database, thanks".